# Passing parameters directly to Dialogflow CX in Voximplant

Tags: dialogflow-cx, voximplant

I have a Voximplant application with Dialogflow CX integration. I want to pass parameters to Dialogflow CX directly, how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
conversationParticipant.analyzeContent({
    eventInput: {
        name: "WELCOME",
        languageCode: languageCode,
        parameters: {
            caller_id: call.callerid(),
            called_number: call.number()
        },
    },
});
```